# Defining object from class template based on user choice and resolving scope for locally defined objects - new question

Tags: c++, templates, scope

I am implementing a queue using two stacks. The whole code is based on template to support multiple data types.

```
#include <iostream>
#define STACKSIZE 100

template <class T>
class Stack
{
private:
    int top;
    T *nodes;
public:
    Stack();
    T gettop();
    bool empty();
    void push(T&);
    T pop();
    ~Stack();
};

template <class T>Stack<T>::Stack()
{
    top=-1;
    nodes=new T[STACKSIZE];
}

template <class T>Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    delete nodes;
}

template <class T> bool Stack<T>::empty()
{
    return(top<0);
}

template <class T> void Stack<T>::push(T&j)
{
    if(top==STACKSIZE-1)
    {
        std::cout<<"Stack Overflow"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
    nodes[++top]=j;
}

template <class T>T Stack<T>::pop()
{
    T p;
    if (empty())
    {
        std::cout<<"Stack Underflow"<<std::endl;
        return p;
    }
    p=nodes[top--];
    return p;
}

template <class T>T Stack<T>::gettop()
{
    return this->top;
}

template <class T>
class Queue
{
    Stack<T>s1;
    Stack<T>s2;
public:
    void insert_into_queue(T data)
    {
        s1.push(data);
        std::cout<<"The value: "<<data<<" has been inserted into the Queue"<<std::endl;
    }
    void delete_from_queue()
    {
        if(s1.empty())
        {
            std::cout<<"The Stack S1 is Empty which implies Queue is Empty, nothing to delete"<<std::endl;
            return;
        }
        while(!s1.empty())
        {
            T top=s1.gettop();
            s1.pop();
            s2.push(top);
        }
        T d_val;
        d_val=s2.gettop();
        s2.pop();
        std::cout<<"The value: "<<d_val<<" has been deleted from the Queue"<<std::endl;
        while(!s2.empty())
        {
            T top=s2.gettop();
            s2.pop();
            s1.push(top);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    char choice;
    int option;
    int val;
    while(1)
    {
    std::cout<<"Provide the choice of DATA to work on: I for Integer, F for float, C for Character"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>choice;
        if (choice == 'I' || choice == 'i')
        {
            Queue<int> q;
            break;
        }
        else if (choice == 'F' || choice == 'f')
        {
            Queue<float> q;
            break;
        }
        else if (choice == 'C' || choice == 'c')
        {
            Queue<char> q;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Not a valid choice" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    while(1)
    {
        std::cout<<"#######################################################################################"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Press 1 to Insert a value into Queue: "<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Press 2 to Delete a value into Queue: "<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Press 3 to Exit the Program"<<std::endl;
        std::cin>>option;
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:
                std::cout<<"Insert the value: "<<std::endl;
                std::cin>>val;
                q.insert_into_queue(val);
                break;
            case 2:
                q.delete_from_queue();
                break;
            case 3:
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                std::cout<<"Selected Option is Invalid"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is i want to get a choice from user to specify datatype for my queue till the user provides a correct input for queue value.

Then i want the user to insert data into queue or delete data from queue or exit from the program.

I tried to pull them using two endless while(1) loops, inside the main() function, but when i do so, i loose the scope of q.

Please suggest suitable modification to the code (or) modify the code to achieve desired functionality.

This question is not the same as other questions referred in the sense that

1. I cannot create a base class for queue as in such a case i cannot define the members

```
 Stack<T>s1;
 Stack<T>s2;
```

and methods

```
 void insert_into_queue(T data)
    {
        s1.push(data);
        std::cout<<"The value: "<<data<<" has been inserted into the Queue"<<std::endl;
    }
    void delete_from_queue()
    {
        if(s1.empty())
        {
            std::cout<<"The Stack S1 is Empty which implies Queue is Empty, nothing to delete"<<std::endl;
            return;
        }
        while(!s1.empty())
        {
            T top=s1.gettop();
            s1.pop();
            s2.push(top);
        }
        T d_val;
        d_val=s2.gettop();
        s2.pop();
        std::cout<<"The value: "<<d_val<<" has been deleted from the Queue"<<std::endl;
        while(!s2.empty())
        {
            T top=s2.gettop();
            s2.pop();
            s1.push(top);
        }
    }
```

which completely depend on template.

Also, q is defined locally if condition

```
 if (choice == 'I' || choice == 'i')
        {
            Queue<int> q;
            break;
        }
```

Now how to resolve scope of q so that

```
 case 1:
                std::cout<<"Insert the value: "<<std::endl;
                std::cin>>val;
                q.insert_into_queue(val);
                break;
```

can be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ is not dynamically typed. So you can't change a type depending on some runtime condition like user input. Whatever you declared, that's what it is.

The easiest way to deal with this is just to make 3 queues. Then, depending on the user's choice of type, insert the value into the one of the three queues.

```cpp
Queue<int> q1;
Queue<float> q2;
Queue<char> q3;

/* ... */

if (choice == 'I' || choice == 'i') {
    q1.insert_into_queue(...);
}
```

If your assignment or challenge requires you to only have one object, you can use `std::variant` to have a space that can be occupied by queues of different types.

```cpp
#include <variant>
std::variant<Queue<int>, Queue<float>, Queue<char>> q;

/* ... */

if (choice == 'I' || choice == 'i') {
    q = Queue<int> {};
}

/* ... */

if (choice == 'I' || choice == 'i') {
    std::get<Queue<int>>(q).insert_into_queue(...);
}
```

You can also avoid such fanciness if you just duplicate your code a bit:

```cpp
if (choice == 'I' || choice == 'i') {
    Queue<int> q;
    while (1) {
        /* ... input loop */
    }
}
```

Or even wrap that duplicated code in a template (whelp, now it's fancy again):

```cpp
if (choice == 'I' || choice == 'i') {
    Queue<int> q;
    while (1) {
        input_loop<int>(q); // implementation left as exercise
    }
}
```

So, you know, there's a lot of ways to solve your problem (but I recommend the easiest one).

Comment: Thank You @parktomatomi. I did something like as you mentioned and its working finally.

Answer (score 0):

Final code for reference of others

```
int main()
{
    char choice;
    int option;
    int val1;
    float val2;
    char val3;
    Queue<int> q1;
    Queue<float> q2;
    Queue<char> q3;
    while(1)
    {
        std::cout<<"Provide the choice of DATA to work on: I for Integer, F for float, C for Character"<<std::endl;
        std::cin>>choice;
        if (choice == 'I' || choice == 'i')
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (choice == 'F' || choice == 'f')
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (choice == 'C' || choice == 'c')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Not a valid choice" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    while(1)
    {
        std::cout<<"#######################################################################################"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Press 1 to Insert a value into Queue: "<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Press 2 to Delete a value into Queue: "<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Press 3 to Exit the Program"<<std::endl;
        std::cin>>option;
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:
                std::cout<<"Insert the value: "<<std::endl;
                if (choice == 'I' || choice == 'i')
                {
                    std::cin>>val1;
                    q1.insert_into_queue(val1);
                }
                else if (choice == 'F' || choice == 'f')
                {
                    std::cin>>val2;
                    q2.insert_into_queue(val2);
                }
                else if (choice == 'C' || choice == 'c')
                {
                    std::cin>>val3;
                    q3.insert_into_queue(val3);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (choice == 'I' || choice == 'i')
                {
                    q1.delete_from_queue();
                }
                else if (choice == 'F' || choice == 'f')
                {
                    q2.delete_from_queue();
                }
                else if (choice == 'C' || choice == 'c')
                {
                    q3.delete_from_queue();
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                std::cout<<"Selected Option is Invalid"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```